# Query by documentId in Firebase Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

When I query data from Firebase Firestore with documentId as field path, I get a different behaviour when running the script on webpage (javascript) and in Firebase Function (Node.js).

This javascript gives me perfect results:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('test')
  .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '<=', 'ccc')
  .get()
  .then(snapshots => { /* results are here */ });
```

by contrast the same code in Firebase Function (Node.js):

```
admin.firestore().collection('test')
  .where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '<=', 'ccc')
  .get()
  .then(snapshots => { /* ... */ });
```

gives me a error:

> Error: { Error: a filter on __name__ must be a document resource name at ClientReadableStream._emitStatusIfDone (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:255:19) at ClientReadableStream._receiveStatus (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:233:8) at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:705:12 code: 3, metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} } }

I use my own document ids and I want to query by these ids. I know I can walk around this problem by querying by some document's inner field, but my question: what is the reason for this different behaviour? Thanks a lot.

My firebase version is 3.17.4

**Edit: This bug was solved and does not appear in Firebase version 3.18.2.**

Comment: This looks like a bug to me.  I've filed a bug report internally with the Firestore team.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is indeed a feature omission from the Node SDK, which we will address in the next release.

You can work around this for now by directly passing a DocumentReference as such:

```
const coll = admin.firestore().collection('test')
coll
  .where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '<=', coll.doc('ccc'))
  .get()
  .then(snapshots => { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: @google-cloud/firestore v0.12.0 includes a fix for this issue.

Comment: sorry to update this thread but I was unable to achieve a where using documentId FieldPath. Always return the "The corresponding value for FieldPath.documentId() must be a string or a DocumentReference" error :/ With either a string or a doc
(using `in` with an array)

Comment: I'm still arguing this with the firestore team.  The net result is FieldPath.documentId is *not* matching on the documentId, but on the refPath (which it gets automatically if passed a document reference).

If you *have* the document reference, why are you using the collectionGroup at *all*?